# Is it possible to transfer the formats of the Google Sheet table when we transfer the data with the QUERY(IMPORTRANGE?

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

Is it possible to transfer formats and colors when transferring data from one table to another, in addition to transferring data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the importrange only imports the display values of the cells, no formulas or other metadata is included.

Comment: Yes, that should be possible. Try looking at the documentation for the google apps scripts. They provide a bunch of added funtionality.